# Converting a string into array in phpGrid for inserting into postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, phpgrid

I am trying to insert a string into an integer array using phpGrid with a PostgreSQL database. I had to convert the array to a string to remove the brackets when displaying data inside the grid for viewing, but when I try to convert the string back into an array upon adding a field, it is not converting to the format {1,2,3,4}. I'm using the string_to_array function that PostgreSQL offers to do so. Here is the code I am using:

```
$dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT array_to_string(field, ', ') as field_to_string FROM tblname");
```

This works as expected (removes the { } from the data being displayed) but when I try to insert, this query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblname (field_to_string) VALUES ('1,2,3,4');
```

and this is what I am trying to insert (convert to array)

```
$arrFields['field_to_string'] = "string_to_array('" . $arrFields['field_to_string'] . "', ',')";

$sqlCrud = $db->db->GetInsertSQL($rs, $arrFields, get_magic_quotes_gpc(), true);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Can you echo sqlCrud and find out the SQL Insert statement by setting its [DEBUG](http://phpgrid.com/documentation/debug/) set to true? It's likely the Insert statement has an error during conversion.

Your PostgreSql should be something similar to the following:

```
INSERT INTO tblname(field_to_string) VALUES ('{1,2,3,4}'::varchar[])
```

You can check out PostGreSql with array to string conversion examples here: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/228-PostgreSQL-Array-The-ANY-and-Contains-trick.html